# How to retain both the search query box and the alphabetical search after clicking on search button and printing result on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created my PHP page where I have searched query field and alphabetical search. After submitting query I am printing result on the same page. The query is working fine, but I want result to be displayed on the same place where I get result from alphabetical search. I.e. alphabetical search is being disappeared after the result comes from the search box. How can I retain both of them the in web page?

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="query" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<?php
  session_start();  
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","journalskart"); /*Database    Connection*/
      //include('inc/search.php');
      $errormsg= "No Record Found...!";
      //search box script start from here
      $alpha = $_GET['query'];
      $min_length = 3;
      if(strlen($alpha) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

          $alpha = htmlspecialchars($alpha); 
          // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

          $alpha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $alpha);
          // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection
          $q1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vendor1
          WHERE (title LIKE '%".$alpha."%') OR (publisher LIKE '%".$alpha."%')") or die(mysqli_error($con));    
          //$noofresult = mysqli_num_rows($q1);
         //echo "$noofresult Result Found<br/>";
         $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($q1);

         if($num_rows > 0)
         { // if one or more rows are returned do following

              while($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)){


               $_SESSION["Title"] = $roww['title']; 
               $_SESSION["Fullset"] = $roww["full_set"];
             $_SESSION["ISSN"] = $roww["issn"]; 
             $_SESSION["Publisher"] = $roww["publisher"]; 
             $_SESSION["Freq"] = $roww["freq"]; 
             $_SESSION["Volume"] = $roww["volume"]; 
             $_SESSION["Issue"] = $roww["issue"]; 
             $_SESSION["Year"] = $roww["year"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Price"] = $roww["price"]; 
             }
             }
             else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
              echo "No results";
            }   
            }//search box script end here
          else{ 




        $alpha="%";
        if (isset($_REQUEST['alpha'])) {
        $alpha = $_REQUEST['alpha']."%";
        }
        $q1 = mysqli_query($con, "select * from vendor1 where title like '$alpha%' " );

      ?>
<div >
  <form action="" method="post" >
    <table  >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div  style="float:left;">
            <CENTER>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>Sort by Alphabet:</FONT>  
              <A HREF="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >All</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=A">A</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=B">B</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=C">C</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=D">D</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=E">E</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=F">F</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=G">G</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=H">H</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=I">I</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=J">J</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=K">K</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=L">L</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=M">M</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=N">N</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=O">O</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=P">P</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=Q">Q</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=R">R</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=S">S</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=T">T</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=U">U</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=V">V</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=W">W</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=X">X</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=Y">Y</A>
              <FONT COLOR=Green>|</FONT> <A HREF="?alpha=Z">Z</A>
            </CENTER>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Full Set</th>
        <th>ISSN</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
        <th>Freq</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Issue</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          $i=1;
          $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($q1);

          if($num_rows==0)
          {
          ?>
        <div align="center">
          <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <?php echo $errormsg; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
          }
          else
          {
          while($roww=mysqli_fetch_array($q1))
          {   
          $_SESSION["Title"] = $roww['title']; 
                   $_SESSION["Fullset"] = $roww["full_set"];
                 $_SESSION["ISSN"] = $roww["issn"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Publisher"] = $roww["publisher"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Freq"] = $roww["freq"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Volume"] = $roww["volume"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Issue"] = $roww["issue"]; 
                 $_SESSION["Year"] = $roww["year"]; 
                     $_SESSION["Price"] = $roww["price"];

            ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="height:100px;float:left;">
              <input name="" type="checkbox" value="">
            </div>
            <div >
              <a href="#">  <b><?php echo $_SESSION["Title"]; ?></b></a>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Fullset"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["ISSN"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Publisher"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Freq"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Volume"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Issue"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Year"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $_SESSION["Price"]; ?></td>
          </div></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }
          $i++;
          }
          }
          echo "$num_rows Results Found";
          ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
</body></html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JavaScript>
  <!--
    document.write(ALPHABET())
    //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition based check to see whether a search has been made

```
<?php  
//general declarations

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {  
    //body of your php code execution  
}  
?>php

<html>  
//your html body  
</html>
```

Comment: Can i have the complete code after applying this to my code.

Comment: Give me the structure of your database please. Export it, copy it and paste it here or mail me anushibin007@gmail.com

Comment: please check out your inbox.